# android json php test outputs garbage

Tags: php, android, json

I am testing an android to PHP interface and PHP to android reply system using JSON. From the Android app it contacts my PHP page and creates an entry into my database as should but the reply from the PHP to android is full of garbage. I was wondering where the problem is:

```
//PHP
<?php 

require_once('functions.php');

$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json,true);



execute("insert into android_test (USERNAME,FULLNAME) values ('".$obj->{'UserName'}."', '".$obj->{'FullName'}."')"); //android_test (ID,IDUSERS,USERNAME,FULLNAME)
execute("commit");

  $posts = array($json);
  //$posts = array(1);

    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(array('posts'=>$posts));


?>
```

the android app:

```
public void clickbuttonRecieve(View v) { //send to server
        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            json.put("UserName", "test2");
            json.put("FullName", "1234567");


            HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams,
                    TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);

            String url = "https://www.mypage.com/scripts/androidportalinput.php"; 

            HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
            request.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(json.toString().getBytes(
                    "UTF8")));
            request.setHeader("json", json.toString());


            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request); //get feedback
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            // If the response does not enclose an entity, there is no need
            if (entity != null) {
                InputStream instream = entity.getContent();

                String result = RestClient.convertStreamToString(instream); //get feedback
                Log.i("Read from server", result);
                Toast.makeText(this,  result,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Request failed: " + t.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

The popup I receive back is the 'posts' but contain the pages html code as well so the json encoded data is full garbage that is sent to my android app.

Any resolving this?

Help please

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but I see this being the following possibilities.

1) You are making a bad request. Try testing the request in a browser to make sure it reply properly there.

2) You serving the request improperly.  Is there any reason you would be including a head/foot in the reply.  Perhaps some how your webserver is adding content/redirecting??

3)The data is getting corrupted in route...probably not...not sure what you could do about this.

4)Your app is corrupting data. Again, unlikely..you can try to display the data once retrieve to minimize the chance of something effecting the data.

If its including html that belongs to your website I'm pretty sure its #2.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use ajax call to get data from functions.php ?
You may go this way if the functions.php generates a json string

$.ajax({

url : 'functions.php',

data : 'your arguments',

dataType : 'json',

success : function (get) {

console.log(get.value);

},

error : function (e) {

console.log(e)

}

});